# How do I show n=m=l from $n^{2}+m^{2}+l^{2}=mn+nl+ml$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the final step of a high school problem. Should it be intuitive that n=m=l or do I have to prove it further? Am I overthinking it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&client=ms-android-samsung-rev2&source=android-browser&q=a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%3Dab%2Bbc%2Bca

Comment: Ohhh thank you so much! I see the light

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try to use the identity
$(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +2ab+2ac+2bc$

and convert the expression into perfect sqaures

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it, I appreciate the hint